# SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For finding an xpath for Google search, we write the below line in console, but at the time of pressing enter by keyboard it shows syntax error.

```
$x{*//title[text()='selenium - Google Search']*}
```

**Syntax error which it shows:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
message: "Unexpected token {"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try this:

```
$x("*//title[text()='selenium - Google Search']*")
```

You shouldn't use '*' at the begin and end of the expression.

And of course if you want to evaluate xpath expression via $x, you should do it like this `$x(...)`, but not like this `$x{...}`.

Comment: It show the below error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '*//title[text()='selenium - Google Search']*' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Try this $x("//title[text()='selenium - Google Search']")

Comment: thanks.. its working, can you please let me know what is the issue?

Comment: @marck, that was just syntax errors. You shouldn't use '*' at the begin and end of the expression. And of course if you want to evaluate xpath expression via $x, you should do it like this $x(...), but not like this $x{...}.

Comment: @marck please accept his answer - it helps give something back to the people who answer your questions.

Comment: @RomanDryndik - please edit your answer with the correct expression, so that it can be accepted for future reference.